# Pass list of links to Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-views

I have a list of urls that I have imported in my settings.py file via:

`from myproject.image_folders_link import Links`

Now my `image_folders_link` contains the following constants:

MY_image_doctors_link = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/doctors"

MY_image_patients_link = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/patients"

Now I want to use it in my Django template. How I can pass this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430451/using-django-settings-in-templates ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a set of constants available in all of your template, you should [write a "context processor"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

I don't really understand what variables you are trying to add, but in general you create a new file in one of your apps called `context_processors.py`:

```
from myproject.image_folders_link import Links

def template_links(request):
    return {
        "MY_image_doctors_link": "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/doctors",
        ...
    }
```

Now add it to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting in your `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'myapp.context_processors.template_links',
)
```

and you can call those variables in all your templates:

```
{{ MY_image_doctors_link }}
```

Comment: Ok got your point. However `{{ MY_image_doctors_link }}` doesn't print the link. I am also using AngularJS in my template. Do I need to define something? As this data is being displayed by the AngularJS.

Comment: Also I use to return `HttpResponse` json dump from my view