# Django page hit counter concurrency

Tags: python, django, concurrency, auto-increment

Im a django newbie. Im making a crude hit counter as an assignment for a course in web programming at Uni. I made a class HitCount:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class HitCount(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
```

And then I use this code in the views file:

```
def index(request):

    #try getting a hitcounter, if there is none, create one
    try:
        hc = HitCount.objects.get(pk=1)
    except: 
        hc = HitCount(count=0)
        hc.save()
        pass

    #get a queryset containing our counter
    hc = HitCount.objects.filter(pk=1)
    #increment its count and update it in db
    hc.update(count=F('count')+1)
    #ATM hc is a queryset, so hc.count will just return how many
    #counters are in the queryset (1). So we have to get the
    #actual counter object
    hc = HitCount.objects.get(pk=1)
    #and return its count
    return render_to_response('hitcount/index.html', {'count': hc.count})
```

This is my index.html file:

```
<p>{{count}}</p>
```

This seems to work just fine, but I wonder:

- Is this a reasonable way of doing this? Should the code for incrementation really reside in the views file? Or should I move it into a method in the class?
- Is this concurrency safe or do I need to use some kind of lock? Part of the assignment is making the counter concurrency safe. I use SQLite, which uses transactions, so I figured it should be all right, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Transactions won't be used automatically. Although it does remove some of the niceties of an ORM, if you're using MySQL, this can be done in a single query: `INSERT INTO hitcount(id,count) VALUES(1,1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1`. This avoids the need for transactions altogether. (You can use `MERGE INTO` for Oracle or SQL server, and a UDF in PostgreS)

Comment: Cheers for your input. Would you mind expanding a little bit? E.g. how does one force the use of transactions? And how come using a manual query removes the need for transactions? Shouldnt there then be a risk that two queries are performed concurrently, leading to an error?

Comment: See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django-s-default-transaction-behavior) for information on how Django handles transactions and how you can have Django automatically use transactions. As for my alternate suggestion, each update is performed in a single statement and treated as atomic by the database server, so no transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off topic, but you should be catching `HitCount.DoesNotExist` in your try/except, since you really only want to execute the code in the except if the HitCount object doesn't exist yet.

If it's possible, you might want to look at something like [Redis](http://redis.io/documentation) (or another key/val store) to do your hit counter.

[Redis](http://redis.io/documentation) provides a method called [INCR](http://redis.io/commands/incr) that will automatically increment a value by 1. It's super fast and a great solution for a hit counter like this. All you need to do is make a key that is related to the page and you can increment that by +1.

It might also make more sense to use a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/) class to track page hits. Much easier than adding it to every view. If you need to display this count on every page, you can use a [context processor](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/) ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831301/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-django-context-processors)) to add the page's hit count into the context. There will be less code repetition this way.

**Edit**

I initially missed that this was for a Uni project, so this might be heavily over engineering for what you need. However, if you were to ever build a hit counter for a production environment, this is what I'd recommend. You can still use the middleware/context processors to do the hit counts/retrieval in a DRY manner.

Comment: This is an excellent answer and great info! While Redis may be slight overkill in this particular case, I will definitely look into moving some of the code into a middleware class, it feels like a better design. Because you provided me with information that arguably answers both my questions, I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Locking is possible in python using the following:

```
lock = Lock()
lock.acquire()
try:
    ... access shared resource
finally:
    lock.release() # release lock, no matter what
```

Keep in mind that method is not safe in a multi-server environment though.

You could also create a more extensible 'logging' solution that tracks each hit as a row in the db with associated info, and then be able to count/query even at a particular date range.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new database row for each hit and call HitCount.objects.count() to get the count.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but arguably it is more clean and lightweight to simply increase the objects count value.